# Is this auto-expansion in Droidio a bug or a feature?

Tags: java, lambda, onclick, android-studio, onclicklistener

In Droidio (Android Studio), code that looks like this in the editor:

```
fetchVendorByCoBtn.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
```

...changes when you click in the "((v) -> {" part.

The reason I clicked was out of curiosity due to the fact that that part is greyed out:

[image]

Clicking changes the code to the following:

```
fetchVendorByCoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

If the new permutation is simply a more verbose way of displaying what was really already hidden behind the greyness...okay...but is it in actuality "6 of one and half a dozen of the other" (only the aesthetics have changed) or has the personality of the code been changed, too?

### UPDATE

I also noticed that copying what appears to be "(v) -> {" and pasting it elsewhere pastes:

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

(not "(v) -> {").

Comment: The lambda has been transformed into an anonymous inner class - that is functionally equivalent.